# when statement with var1 contain in var2 ( can this be done?)

Tags: ansible

```
# This playbook to test define var
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    var1: 100
    var2: "contain 100"

  tasks:

  - name: test var1 inside of var2
    debug:
      msg: "var1 is inside var2"
    when:  var1 is in var2
```

This does not work

> PLAY [127.0.0.1] ***********************************************************************************
>
> TASK [test var1 inside of var2] ********************************************************************
> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'var1 is in var2' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if var1 is in var2 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): 'in ' requires string as left operand, not int\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/cngo/ansible/p79/define_var.yml': line 14, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: test var1 inside of var2\n    ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear:  `'in' requires string as the left operand, not int`. Ansible is not able to search an integer in a string. `var1` shall be a string

```yaml
  vars:
    var1: "100"
```

Another option is to [`quote`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) the variable if you're not able to change the declaration of `var1`

```yaml
    when:  var1|quote is in var2
```

, or

```yaml
    when:  var2 is search(var1|quote)
```